# Rotate bitmap - Android

Tags: android, android-bitmap

I'm trying to rotate a bitmap in Android using the following function, the image is getting distorted with some degrees, like 70, how can I rotate an image without distorting it in any degree?

```
public Bitmap rotateBitmap (Bitmap bm, int degree) {
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.setRotate(degree, bm.getWidth() / 2, bm.getHeight() / 2);

    return Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, bm.getWidth(), bm.getHeight(), matrix, true);


}
```

Comment: Please upload some screenshots to imgur.com and insert the links (or embed with `<img>` tag) in your question.  That way, we can see what you are referring to.

Answer (score 1):

Hello there use this function!

```
public static Bitmap RotateBitmap(Bitmap source, float angle) {
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postRotate(angle);
        return Bitmap.createBitmap(source, 0, 0, source.getWidth(),
                source.getHeight(), matrix, true);
    }
```

You can use this function like this :

```
Bitmap bmp : RotateBitmap(b,90);
```

Hope this works for you !:)